# overlayfs: remount doesn't change parameters

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to `mount -o remount` an overlayfs in order to change to an updated `lowerdir`:

```
$ mount -t overlay ovl /mnt -oworkdir=/.work -oupperdir=/upper -olowerdir=/lower
$ mount -t overlay ovl /mnt -oworkdir=/.work -oupperdir=/upper -olowerdir=/lower-new -o remount
```

The remount seems to work, but no change happens. `mount` still shows the old `upperdir`:

```
$ mount
...
ovl on /mnt type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,workdir=/.work)
```

I would have expected for the mount parameter to change and for the files coming from lowerdir to be updated accordingly, or for the remount to give an error (with strong preference for the update ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately not a solution, but https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9a5682765a2e5f93cf2fe7b612b8072b18f0c68a/fs/overlayfs/super.c#L368 confirms that what you’re seeing is not a bug or misuse, but rather overlayfs only picks up read-only changes when remounting :(

Comment: I can see how changing parameters could lead to bad situations.
For instance - remounting / (root) with a different set of lower and upper dirs, you could brick your system, requiring a reboot. However, if you know what you're doing, remounting different uppers could allow you to significantly change the behavior of your os, without having to reboot.